# For all $n \geq 2$ we have $\nu_2\left(\binom{4n}{2n}-(-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}\right)=s_2(n)+2+3 \nu_2(n).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

A theorem from my number theory book:

> For all $n \geq 2$
> $$
> \nu_2\left(\binom{4n}{2n}-(-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}\right)=s_2(n)+2+3 \nu_2(n),
> $$
> where $s_2(n)$ is the binary digit sum and $\nu_2$ is the $2$-adic evaluation.

The book gives this proof:

*Proof:* Note that
$$
\frac{\binom{4n}{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{(4 n) !}{(2 n) !} \cdot\left(\frac{n !}{(2 n) !}\right)^2
$$
holds and that for all $k$
$$
\frac{(2 k) !}{k !}=\frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2 k \cdot 1 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot(2 k-1)}{k !}=2^k \cdot 1 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot(2 k-1).
$$
We conclude that
$$
\binom{4n}{2n}-(-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}=\binom{2n}{n} \frac{F_n(4 n)}{(2 n-1) ! !},
$$
where
$$
(2n-1)!!=1 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots \cdot(2 n-1)
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
    F_n(X)=(X-1) \cdot(X-3) \cdot \ldots \cdot(X-2n+1)-(-1) \cdot(-3) \cdot \ldots \cdot(1-2n).
\end{aligned}
$$
A brutal expansion shows that
$$\color{red}{F_n(X)=-n^2 X+\frac{1}{6}n\left(1-4n+3n^2\right)X^2+\ldots,}
$$
thus
$$
F_n(4 n)=-4 n^3+\frac{8}{3} n^3\left(1-4 n+3 n^2\right)+\ldots
$$
For the first term $$\nu_2\left(4 n^3\right)=2+3 \nu_2(n),$$ and for the next one
$$
\nu_2\left(\frac{8}{3} n^3\left(1-4 n+3 n^2\right)\right) \geq 3+3 \nu_2(n).
$$
All other terms are multiples of $(4 n)^3$. Thus, the strong triangle inequality yields
$$
\nu_2 \left(F_n(4 n)\right)=2+3 \nu_2(n) .
$$
Combining this relation with $$\nu_2\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)=s_2(n),$$ which is obtained from Kummer's theorem, the assertion follows. $\square$

---

My question is: Why does the red marked part hold true? I calculated for example
$$
F_4(X)=(X-1)(X-3)(X-5)(X-7)-(-1)(-3)(-5)(-7)=X^4-16X^3+86X^2-176X.
$$
The linear term is not the square of $n$, in fact, it is not even a perfect square, it is $(4\sqrt{11})^2$.

In the proof it says ... at the end of that line so is the term split and the rest of it is at the end?

Comment: Also the term of $X^2$ in the red $F_n(X)$ is wrong. Instead of $86$ for $n=4$ it would give $22$. So there must be a misunderstanding. The "brutal" expansion failed - no wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the proof you've given doesn't make sense, since $-n^2$ is the coefficient of the $X^{n-1}$ term, not the $X$ term.  Also, I think the coefficient $\frac{1}{6}n\left(1-4n+3n^2\right)$ should be $\frac{1}{6}n\left(1-4n^2+3n^3\right)$, but this is the coefficient of the $X^{n-2}$ term, not the $X^2$ term.

However, I think this result is still true.  Going back to the definition of $F_n(X)$, we can write
$$
F_n(X)=A X + B X^2 + C(X) X^3, \qquad \hbox{$A$, $B\in\mathbb Z$, $C(X)\in{\mathbb Z}[X]$.}
$$
We want to show that $\nu_2(F_n(4n))=2+3 \nu_2(n)$.  Let
$$
\tilde{H}_n:=\sum_{1\le i\le n}\frac{1}{2i-1};
$$
then $A=(-1)^{n-1}(2n-1)!! \tilde H_n$,
and as explained in [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244430/2-adic-valuation-of-odd-harmonic-sums),
$
\nu_2(\tilde H_n)=2 \nu_2(n),
$
so $\nu_2(4nA)=2+3\nu_2(n)$.

It's clear that $\nu_2((4n)^3 C(4n))>2+3\nu_2(n)$, so we will be done if we can show that $\nu_2((4n)^2B)\ge 3+3\nu_2(n)$, i.e., $\nu_2(2B)\ge \nu_2(n)$.  But
\begin{eqnarray*}
2B&=&(-1)^{n-2}(2n-1)!! \sum_{1\le i<j\le n} \frac 2 {(2i-1)(2j-1)}\\
&=& (-1)^{n-2}(2n-1)!!\left(\tilde H_n^2 - \sum_{1\le i\le n} \frac 1 {(2i-1)^2}
\right),
\end{eqnarray*}
and by the above, $\nu_2(\tilde H_n^2)=4\nu_2(n)$, so we will be done if we can show that
$$
\nu_2(\sum_{1\le i\le n} \frac 1 {(2i-1)^2})=\nu_2(n).
$$
Let $n=2^k l$ with $l$ odd, so that $k=\nu_2(n)$.  Looking at the sum modulo $2^{k+1}$, we want to prove that its congruence class is that of $2^k$.  However, the sum is of the squares of the reciprocals of the odd residue classes modulo $2^{k+1}$, each odd residue class taken $l$ times.  Modulo $2^{k+1}$, this is the same as taking the sum of the squares of the odd residue classes modulo $2^{k+1}$, each taken $l$ times, so
$$\sum_{1\le i\le n} \frac 1 {(2i-1)^2} \equiv l \sum_{1\le i\le 2^{k}} (2i-1)^2=l\frac{4\cdot 2^{3k}-2^{k}}3\equiv 2^k\qquad\qquad({\rm mod}\ 2^{k+1}).$$